# Why does Launchpad not remember my icon settings?

Tags: macos, launchpad

I'm trying to use the Launchpad feature in Mac OS X, but my icons keep on getting rearranged.

I'll manually move icons around to my liking, but then after a restart, many of them are automatically rearranged to a different order than what I specified.

Note: It doesn't add an icon to a folder nor does it remove an icon from a folder. I've only seen it rearrange folders or icons which aren't in folders.

Why is this happening, and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: It's a known bug. You can reset LaunchPad but eventually, over time, icon locations will still rearrange themselves arbitrarily. This has been around since 10.7 and so far, there are no signs it has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Apple Discussion [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3225106?start=0&tstart=0) that describes the same problem, and refers to [this](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/01/refresh-launchpad-in-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/) OSX Dialy link on how to correctly refresh LaunchPad, and fix a corrupted LaunchPad.

The short version of the answer is:

> Basically I used terminal to kill the dock with the command "killall Dock"
>
> Then I had to delete the dock database file located in "Home Folder/Library/Application Support/Dock" you get to your Library folder by holding down the option key while clicking "Go" in Finder.
>
> Then kill the dock again with the terminal command "killall Dock".
>
> Finally After putting all my apps back where I wanted them they are now saving.